# Is there an Android API to test the physical memory or other hardware

Tags: android, testing, hardware

I have tablets deployed in an enterprise situation.  A handful of users have reported that their Android systems (GT2 7" LTE tablets) just shut off without warning.  Since it's only a handful (4 or 5) out of many, I wanted to test to see if the memory or other hardware is failing and causing this strange behavior.

**Is there a way to perform hardware tests in Android via an API?** In particular, memory checksums?  How about battery health?  I have found nothing in the documentation so far that pertains to hardware except camera, sensors, etc..., but if someone could point me in the right direction...?  Explicitly, I am not looking for my apps' memory usage.

Since the tablets are out of warranty, I would like to test them myself, before shipping them to Samsung for inspection.

Comment: I thought you got crash reports if the app crashes...

Comment: @jyoon - tablets just turn off - no reporting whatsoever is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Use Android Studio IDE. There is a option near console to view memory usage.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I am looking for a software solution via an app, so that I can report on the health of each tablet's hardware.